# create comparison trait for template classes whose parameters are in a different order

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, type-traits

### UPDATE

My fully-featured implementation of T.C.'s answer can be found [on GitHub.](https://github.com/nholthaus/units)

### QUESTION:

I'm writing a unit conversion library. It's currently header-only and no dependencies, which I'd like to preserve if possible.

In the library, compound units are defined as templates of simple units:

```
template<class... Units>
struct compound_unit { //...};
```

For simplicity, think of all the types as pure tags, and so I can define a compound unit as:

```
struct meters {};
struct seconds {};

template<class Unit>
inverse { //... };

struct meters_per_second : 
    compound_unit<meters, inverse<seconds>> {};
```

where inverse is just another template representing 1/seconds in this case.

**There are a LOT of compound units one could make though, so I can't make any assumptions about the number of variadic arguments that `compound_unit` will take.**

The problem is, since compound units are just a bunch of simple units multiplied together, and multiplication is transitive, that in order to properly compare compound units, I need to define some type-trait that considers the following two classes to be equivalent:

```
struct meters_per_second : 
    compound_unit<meters, inverse<seconds>> {};

struct other_meters_per_second : 
    compound_unit<inverse<seconds>, meters> {};

magical_comparison_trait<meters_per_second, other_meters_per_second>::value; // == true
```

Certainly c++ in a generic case could never assume that template parameters in a different order would represent the same type, so I'm wondering if it's possible to make such a trait, and if so, how to go about implementing it.

**BONUS POINTS**

I'm OK with limiting `compound_unit` to be composed *only* of simple unit types, but the template would still work if I composed `compound_unit` from a mix of simple *and* other compound units (and the rest of my library already could handle this case if I had the right trait). It would be **way** cooler if the trait could also decompose nested compound units, and still compare the equivalence.

example:

```
struct acceleration_1 : compound_unit<meters_per_second, inverse<second>> {};
struct acceleration_2 : compound_unit<meters, inverse<second>, inverse<second>> {};
```

Comment: If you may provide a comparer for type, you may sort them and equality check.

Comment: I assume that you have already simplified cases like `compound_unit<inverse<seconds>, seconds>`

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah I'm trying to figure out how to deal with it for the general variadic case where the unit may be composed of 5 or 6 other things, or heaven forbid, other `compound_unit`s as well.

Comment: I know you said you are reluctant to use boost in a comment on an answer... but boost actually has a dimensional analysis library which seems like it might be exactly what you are trying to do. It might be one of the libraries that is implemented as header only as well... I forget.

Comment: @RyanP : Boost.Units is indeed header-only.

Comment: @RyanP For another application, I'm sure I could, but the units library is actually part of another bigger library that there is no boost equivalent for, and it made making the big library a lot easier to define my own units. I could actually trivially solve by the problem by using consistent type definitions, I just don't want to.

Comment: There are only so many SI base units. I'd normalize it to a canonical sequence.

Comment: @T.C. as usual I think I agree with you...

Comment: What do you mean by decompose the nested compound units and then compare? Could you give an example?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my answer will allow for that if you device the IDs I mentioned cleverly (which may become complicated).

Comment: I updated my answer to show that the bonus part works.

Comment: Thank you for your units library Nicolas. It is very well done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_permutation` is O(N^2) when the only thing you can do is compare for equality, plus it doesn't handle your other use cases. Since there are only so many SI base units, a better approach is to canonicalize your units.

General SI unit class whose template parameters represent exponents:

```
template<class Meter, class Kilogram, class Second,
         class Ampere, class Kelvin, class Candela, class Mole>
struct unit {};
```

Multiply two units:

```
template<class, class> struct unit_multiply_impl;
template<class... Exps1, class... Exps2>
struct unit_multiply_impl<unit<Exps1...>, unit<Exps2...>> {
    using type = unit<std::ratio_add<Exps1, Exps2>...>;
};

template<class U1, class U2>
using unit_multiply = typename unit_multiply_impl<U1, U2>::type;
```

Inverse:

```
template<class U> struct inverse_impl;
template<class... Exps>
struct inverse_impl<unit<Exps...>> {
    using type = unit<std::ratio_multiply<Exps, std::ratio<-1>>...>;
};

template<class U> using inverse = typename inverse_impl<U>::type;
```

Compound = multiply them all:

```
template<class U, class... Us> struct compound_impl;
template<class U> struct compound_impl<U> { using type = U; };
template<class U1, class U2, class...Us>
struct compound_impl<U1, U2, Us...>
    :  compound_impl<unit_multiply<U1, U2>, Us...> {};

template<class U, class... Us>
using compound_unit = typename compound_impl<U, Us...>::type;
```

Tests:

```
using std::ratio;
using meters = unit<ratio<1>, ratio<0>, ratio<0>, ratio<0>, ratio<0>, ratio<0>, ratio<0>>;
using seconds = unit<ratio<0>, ratio<0>, ratio<1>, ratio<0>, ratio<0>, ratio<0>, ratio<0>>;

using mps = compound_unit<meters, inverse<seconds>>;
using mps = compound_unit<inverse<seconds>, meters>;

using acc = compound_unit<mps, inverse<seconds>>;
using acc = compound_unit<meters, inverse<seconds>, inverse<seconds>>;
```

A big benefit of this approach is that `compound_unit<mps, inverse<seconds>>` and `compound_unit<meters, inverse<seconds>, inverse<seconds>>` are actually the same type.

Comment: The problem I see with using `std::ratio` is that there are a ton of unit conversions I need to do which have irrational conversion factors and can't be represented by a ratio of integers.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, using any form of irrational numbers with templates is going to be a problem since you can't use floats or doubles as template arguments. How else could you implement an irrational number which can be used with the template method the question suggests you want?

Comment: @nabla, true, but I don't put the conversion factor *in* the template currently, for exactly that reason. They're in `constexpr` or `static` functions

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus What irrational conversion factors are we talking about? I know that pi likes to show up; anything else?

Comment: Yeah looking through it I think it is only conversions which have pi as a factor, but my unit library was built to support a geodetic datum conversion library so it's central to the whole thing. I can't use any rational approximation of pi because none are sufficiently accurate.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus You can just treat pi as an extra "base unit", in that case (unless you want to do something like `meter^pi`)?

Comment: @T.C. I don't think I'm fully clear on the example of where/how the conversion math is actually intended to be done. With pi as a base unit the actual double value would have to go... somewhere? Think you could add degrees/radians?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus Here we just have a representation of the unit in the type system. You can add a compile-time scale (expressed as, say, `ratio * (pi ^ ratio)` ) on top of it, along with e.g., a `double`, that actually stores the value.

Comment: I'm working on a full implementation based on this idea, and having pi worked into the templates with the base units breaks the 'big benefit' a little, since now units which need to be scaled by pi aren't the same type as units which don't. Example: a parsec, which has a factor of pi^-1 to convert to meters, isn't the same type as meters anymore, even though both are units of length defined in terms of meters. A `unit_compatibility` trait can be written to work around this though for conversion. If more than 1 or two irrationals are needed, it probably gets untenable.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus It's probably better to handle pi as part of the scale rather than part of the base unit (so instead of using one `ratio` for the scale, you'd use two).

Comment: I'm using two ratios now, one for pi and one for a rational factor, but they're both going in through the `unit` template, along with the base unit exponent ratios. I guess I'm not sure where else they'd go; it seems to me like the units themselves need to carry around their scale factor.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus I'd implement something like a `template<class Scale, class PiExp, class Unit> class scaled_unit;` on top of `unit` which just handles the base unit. Two `scaled_unit`s would be convertible iff they have the same `Unit`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstood the question, you want to check if two type lists are equal to each other, independently from the ordering of the types.

Example:

```
<int, char> /*is equal to*/ <char, int>
<int, float, char> /*is equal to*/ <char, int, float>
```

Assuming that's the case, here's a possible naive solution using [boost::hana](http://boostorg.github.io/).

It checks if the type lists of two `compound_unit` are subsets of each other, and checks if the size of the type lists is equal.

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
using namespace boost;

template <typename... Ts>
struct compound_unit
{
    constexpr auto type_tuple()
    {
        return hana::tuple_t<Ts...>;
    }
};

template <typename TCU0, typename TCU1>
constexpr bool same_compound_unit(TCU0 cu0, TCU1 cu1)
{
    constexpr auto tt0(cu0.type_tuple());
    constexpr auto tt1(cu1.type_tuple());

    return (hana::is_subset(tt0, tt1) && hana::is_subset(tt1, tt0)) &&
           (hana::size(tt0) == hana::size(tt1));
}

int main()
{

    static_assert(same_compound_unit(compound_unit<int, float, char>{},
                      compound_unit<float, char, int>{}),
        "");

    static_assert(!same_compound_unit(compound_unit<int, float, char>{},
                      compound_unit<int, float, char, int>{}),
        "");

    static_assert(same_compound_unit(compound_unit<float, float, char>{},
                      compound_unit<char, float, char>{}),
        "");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll try and replicate this. Right now my library is header-only with no dependencies so I'm reluctant to use any boost.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? I'm not 100% confident I understand the question completely. This solution basically checks if two type lists are equal to each other without taking the ordering into account. (Check the edited answer).

Comment: yeah, your understanding of the question is correct. my other comment still stands though.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus : Boost.Hana is itself free of dependencies, even from the rest of Boost. So it's an extremely light dependency, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which I think meets your requirements, although, there are some things which are not so good.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define METERS  1
#define SECONDS 3
#define INV     5

// ------- Start Unroll
// Unroll calculates the value of a compound type
template <typename... Type>
struct Unroll;

template <typename Type1, typename... Types> 
struct Unroll<Type1,Types...> {
    static constexpr int value = Type1::value * Unroll<Types...>::value;
};

template <typename Type>
struct Unroll<Type> {
    static constexpr int value = Type::value;
};

template <>
struct Unroll<> {
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};

// ---------- End Unroll

// Same definitions as in the question

template <typename... Units>
struct compound_unit {
    static constexpr int value = Unroll<Units...>::value;
};

struct meters {
    static constexpr int value = METERS;
};

struct seconds {
    static constexpr int value = SECONDS;
};

template <typename Unit>
struct inverse {
    // The -1 here can be anything, so long as is doesn't result in any of values which are defined at the top
    static constexpr int value = Unit::value * INV;
};

struct mps : compound_unit<meters, inverse<seconds>> {};
struct mps2 : compound_unit<inverse<seconds>, meters> {};

// Does the conversion using the Unroll struct to check that values are the same
template <typename T, typename V>
struct comparison_trait {
    static constexpr bool value = (T::value == V::value);
};

// Update for Bonus:

struct acc : compound_unit<mps, inverse<seconds>> {};
struct acc2 : compound_unit<meters, inverse<seconds>, inverse<seconds>> {};    

int main()
{
    bool check = comparison_trait<mps, mps2>::value;
    std::cout << "MPS check : " << check;

    bool check1 = comparison_trait<acc, acc2>::value;
    std::cout << "ACC check : " << check1;    
}
```

This basically works by defining a unique 'ID', using the `#define`'s at the top, for each of the units, and then uses those to calculate a similar unique `ID` for each `compound_type` using the `Unroll` struct.

The obvious disadvantage is having to define the unique ID's for each of the units. To avoid ID collisions (`1*4 == 2*2`), the ID's need to be chosen cleverly, for example using prime numbers as Jarod42 suggested.  You could also work the IDs into the structs directly or using the template system if you wanted.

The second disadvantage is that the templated code is not so easy to read. It does do the job though.

Here is a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6df54699e057c5ef), which is updated for the bonus part of the question.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. My template code is so recursive and unreadable already that it's not a big deal.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus, added a link to the demo so you can mess around with it. Hopefully it does what you want.

Comment: Another disadvantage I could see is in a case with a lot of units, the multiplied ID's might become ambiguous, i.e. 1*4 ==4 and 2*2 == 4.

Comment: Didn't think about that, I'll try come up with a solution.

Comment: Compile time hash function would solve the problem, so hash(1) * hash(4) != hash(2) * hash(2), would this help?

Comment: Or using prime numbers.

Comment: @Jarod42, I like that idea, it's much simpler.

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks, updated answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Would it be possible to use an `enum` instead of preprocessor macros?  You get type safety that way, and you can still assign individual values.  Maybe something like: `enum class UnitID : int { METERS = 1, SECONDS = 2, /* ..., */ INVERSE = -1 };`, which lets you assign values as `UnitID::METERS`, `UnitID::SECONDS`, etc.  (Or just a standard `enum` instead of an `enum class`, if you don't want to have to scope the IDs.)

Comment: @JustinTime, enum class doesn't seem to work as it fails to convert UnitID to int, however, using just a standard enum does. If you did want to scope though, then using a namespace with static constexpr int definitions would achieve the same result.

Comment: @nabla Oh yeah, forgot `enum class` doesn't like to decay back to its base type.  My bad.